# Word(s) for cardboard box whose flaps slide into slots to hold lid closed

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

What is the word(s) for the type of cardboard box whose lid can be held closed without tape. Specifically, the sides have slots and the lid has flaps that slide into the slots to be held in place by friction. These types of boxes are commonly used as product boxes for computer motherboards, hard drives, and feature phones.

[image]

Comment: @NigelJ as opposed to words that were in the dictionary when the big bang happened? All words are invented by humans (and [many of them by their inventors, including sales people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks)). Let's not judge a word by its creator. ;)

Comment: @NigelJ http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-locking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ask your vendors/manufacturers as manufacturers use slightly different terms for their box products, but here's an example:

Excerpts from [Types Of Cardboard Box](http://www.nuttall-packaging.co.uk/our-boxes/):

> **Self Locking**
>   [image: Self Locking]
>   Initially, these boxes are supplied flat for storage purposes and are very easy to assemble into strong packing style boxes. Designs can be modified to include locking tabs, handles, display panels and more depending on your requirements.
>   ...
>
> ---
>
> **Self Locking Tray**
>   [image: Self Locking Tray]
>   Self locking boxes/trays, these are stackable when loaded with product, generally used for packing tins, jars or bottles, you will often see these trays in supermarkets printed with product details or brand image.
>   ...
>
> ---
>
> **Die Cut Self Locking**
>   [image: Die Cut Self Locking]
>   Often used for shipping small components or as an alternative mailer pack (See below for image). Die Cut boxes are quick and easy to assemble and the nature of the style gives excellent protection through the post once they are made up.
>   ...

Comment: Hi @johnlee, links sometimes go stale. On Stack Exchange, the norm is for answers to be self-contained, with links used to verify what the answer itself says. Your post claims that there are multiple variants used to describe what the OP wants, but it doesn't actually provide any word that the OP can use. If there are equally viable alternatives, you should list them (and then add a link to each to show the words in use).

Comment: @Lawrence: Valid point. The answer's edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a self-locking cardboard box, as shown here: https://www.google.com/search?q=self+locking+cardboard+boxes&client=firefox-b-1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL5vO1uYTbAhVO4GMKHcWEBrwQsAR6BAgAEGg&biw=810&bih=548

tab lock cardboard box is another search term that may find similar boxes.

Comment: +1, but can you be more specific? The "self-locking" search term in your URL doesn't necessitate the question's type of self-lock. Your URL's [5th image result](https://www.google.com/search?q=self+locking+cardboard+boxes&client=firefox-b-1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL5vO1uYTbAhVO4GMKHcWEBrwQsAR6BAgAEGg&biw=810&bih=548#imgrc=q5oEG4vfY7BG7M:) (at the moment) concerns a crash-lock base, which doesn't imply its box has a lid that closes via flap-slot insertion.

Comment: I think with the "self-locking" term you should be able to search for what you're looking for.